# Javascript count how many selected from multiple selects

Tags: javascript, html

**This is HTML:**

```html
<select class="form-control selectVitrat" name="PVSuperior" id="PVSuperior">
      <option value="NO">NU</option>
      <option value="YES">DA</option>
    </select>
<select class="form-control selectVitrat" name="PVIntermediar9" id="PVIntermediar9">
      <option value="NO">NU</option>
      <option value="YES">DA</option>
    </select>
<select class="form-control selectVitrat" name="PVIntermediar8" id="PVIntermediar8">
      <option value="NO">NU</option>
      <option value="YES">DA</option>
    </select>
```

How can I count how many Yes I selected from these multiple selections?

Comment: I see no JavaScript here. What have you tried?

Comment: `var count = $(".selectVitrat :selected").length;`

Comment: It returns all my selections number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all the `select`. And using `for` loop, you can check how many `select` have YES values:

```js
function checkTotalYes() {
  var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++) {
    if (selectElements[i].value == 'YES')
      count++;
  }
  console.log('Total Yes: ' + count);
}

checkTotalYes();
```

```html
<select class="form-control selectVitrat" name="PVSuperior" id="PVSuperior" onchange="checkTotalYes()">
  <option value="NO">NU</option>
  <option value="YES">DA</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control selectVitrat" name="PVIntermediar9" id="PVIntermediar9" onchange="checkTotalYes()">
  <option value="NO">NU</option>
  <option value="YES">DA</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control selectVitrat" name="PVIntermediar8" id="PVIntermediar8" onchange="checkTotalYes()">
  <option value="NO">NU</option>
  <option value="YES">DA</option>
</select>
```